# Reading port numbers of a switch configured with V1

Tags: sharp-snmp

SNMP agent on switch is configured with V1. I am using lextm snmp library VersionCode.V2 to fetch port numbers which is not working. Should the versions match to fetch the info?

Answer (score 0):

According to [SNMPv1 & SNMPv2c interoperability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_Network_Management_Protocol#SNMPv1_.26_SNMPv2c_interoperability), it appears they do:

```
As presently specified, SNMPv2c is incompatible with SNMPv1 in two key
areas: message formats and protocol operations. SNMPv2c messages use
different header and protocol data unit (PDU) formats from SNMPv1 messages.
SNMPv2c also uses two protocol operations that are not specified in SNMPv1.
Furthermore, RFC 2576 defines two possible SNMPv1/v2c coexistence
strategies: proxy agents and bilingual network-management systems.
```

Any reason why you have chosen to implement the client in v2 when targeting a v1 agent?